# Разница между asp.net core и asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

В интернете часто встречаю два эти названия. Это разные технологии или просто два названия одного и того же фраемворка? И если разница есть объясните её пожалуйста.

Comment: Разные технологии

Answer (score 3):

[ASP.NET Core](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/aspnet/what-is-aspnet-core) это кроссплатформенный фреймворк для построения веб приложений. [ASP.NET Core MVC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) это одна из его частей, наряду с другими частями, как Razor Pages или Web API или Blazor и т.д.